# Get the row values as column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have below table,and need to get row values as an output.
This is a part of a view in Oracle Database.

[image]

I need to get the output using SQL as below.`name,address,region`are taking from another table by referring`ID` .

[image]

Looking for much simple way since full query have more than 15 columns and below also need to be added as columns.

Thanks.

Comment: There are ton's of question asked here to achieve  `Pivot`. Couldn't  you find  a single answer?

Comment: @KaushikNayak - to be fair this isn't a straightforward pivot requirement.

Answer (score 3):

> "Looking for much simple way since full query have more than 15 columns"

Sorry, you can have a complex query or no query at all :)

The problem is the structure of the posted table mandates a complex query. That's because it uses a so-called "generic data model", which is actually a data anti-model. The time saved in not modelling the requirement and just smashing values into the table is time you will have to spend writing horrible queries to get those values out again.

I assume you need to drive off the other table you referred to, and the posted table contains attributes supplementary to the core record.

```
select ano.id
       , ano.name
       , ano.address 
       , ano.region 
       , t1.value as alt_id
       , t2.value as birth_date
       , t3.value as contact_no
from another_table ano
     left outer join ( select id, value 
                       from generic_table
                       where key = 'alt_id' ) t1 
          on ano.id = t1.id
     left outer join ( select id, value 
                       from generic_table
                       where key = 'birth_date' ) t2 
          on ano.id = t2.id
     left outer join ( select id, value 
                       from generic_table
                       where key = 'contact_no' ) t3
          on ano.id = t3.id
```

Note the need to use outer joins: one of the problems with generic data models is the enforcement of integrity constraints. Weak data typing can also be an issue (say if you wanted to convert the `birth_date` string into an actual date).

Comment: Thanks ton...!!! You got my point well. Yes this is a supplementary part of core record, that is why I looked for easiest way. Thank you for valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

`PIVOT` concept fits well for these types of problems :

```
SQL> create table person_info(id int, key varchar2(25), value varchar2(25));
SQL> create table person_info2(id int, name varchar2(25), address varchar2(125), region varchar2(25));
SQL> insert into person_info values(4150521,'contact_no',772289317);
SQL> insert into person_info values(4150522,'alt_id','98745612V');
SQL> insert into person_info values(4150522,'birth_date',date '1990-04-21');
SQL> insert into person_info values(4150522,'contact_no',777894561);

SQL> insert into person_info2 values(4150521,'ABC','AAAAAA','ASD');
SQL> insert into person_info2 values(4150522,'XYZ','BBBBB','WER');

SQL> select p1.id, name, address, region, alt_id, birth_date, contact_no  
  from person_info
 pivot
(
 max(value) for key in ('alt_id' as alt_id,'birth_date' as birth_date,'contact_no' as contact_no)
) p1 join person_info2 p2 on (p1.id = p2.id);

ID      NAME    ADDRESS REGION  ALT_ID      BIRTH_DATE  CONTACT_NO
------- ------- ------- ------  ---------   ----------  ----------
4150521 ABC     AAAAAA  ASD     12345678V   21-APR-89   772289317
4150522 XYZ     BBBBB   WER     98745612V   21-APR-90   777894561
```